# Display all data in one column in a listview SQLite Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new to SQLite and am trying to show all the data in the 'name' column into a ListView in Android Studio. However I am getting both the 'name' and 'age' data show in my ListView. Below is my current code.

usersScreen.java

```
   private void populateListView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

    //get the data and append to a list
    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();

    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        //get the value from the database in column 1
        //then add it to the ArrayList
        listData.add(data.getString(data.getColumnIndex( "name" )));
    }
    //create the list adapter and set the adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
    public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COL2 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}

public Cursor getItemID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}

  public boolean addDataName(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for how you are inserting/adding the data to the database. I can't see any obvious issue you appear to be just getting the one column, so my thought is that you may be storing both values in the same column when you add/insert a row.

Comment: I believe this is now up to date with the code used for adding data to the database, thank you for looking at this. No idea what is wrong with it. Thanks!